Cape Datum conversion
I need to convert Cape Datum (Clarke 1880) coordinates of one of my properties to more recent/accurate coordinates I can use.  This is very confusing for me.


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, not a tutorial or contract services site. We take the "If you teach a person to fish..." proverb quite seriously here. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Please [Edit] the Question to specify the GIS software you are using, what you have tried, and where you are stuck. I suspect you'd be best off contacting a local surveyor, since there is rather large learning curve awaiting.

Attention: in addition to the figure, provide the information in a recognized textual and digital form, so that the responder can perform tests on your raw data, respect the time of the responder to your question!

Use the "Y" column as-is, and add 2,700,000 to the "X" column to get coordinates in EPSG:22291 Cape/Lo31. In QGIS save this in coordinate system EPSG:4326. That will give you Lats and Longs in WGS84.
I encourage you to do this work on your own to verify, and if you have any sticking points, please post your specific question.
y, x, name, WGS84longitude, WGS84latitude

-6884.96, 2776877.81, A, 31.068, -25.1

-6848.67, 2777025.8, B, 31.068, -25.102

-6815.2, 2776939.29, C, 31.067, -25.101

-7033.78, 2776408.92, D, 31.07, -25.096

-6842.2, 2777112.18, E, 31.068, -25.102

-6873.87, 2777119.17, F, 31.068, -25.103

-11456.6, 2775375.01, Burgershall, 31.113, -25.087

-10488.17, 2783543.57, Matimba, 31.104, -25.161



@TomazicM, thank you. How did you do that?

A bit of manual work: enclose everything as code and put space after comma :-).
